# Why doesn't IE render letter-spacing after the last letter?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<span style="letter-spacing: 5px;">Red<span style="letter-spacing: 0px;">Blue</span></span>
```

Looks like this in IE:

R e dBlue


But like this in other browsers:


R e d Blue

Is there any way I can get IE to render it the way other browsers do?

Comment: Seems to work fine on IE8, but not on IE7

Comment: Pad-left the span 5px? (using a conditional, of course ;)

Comment: Letter-spacing is between letters. The letter spacing between d and B is ambiguous, could be 5px, could be 0px. Looks like some browsers opt for the one, some opt for the other variant. Probably this is even specified within CSS, but not all browsers follow the standard to all it's details.

Comment: Check out Example XV here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#letter-spacing0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is off above.  You have not closed the first `span` where I think you want it to be closed.

Try this first

`<span style="letter-spacing: 5px;">Red</span><span style="letter-spacing: 0px;">Blue</span>`

If that doesn't fix it, why not add a `&nbsp;` between them, like so:

`<span style="letter-spacing: 5px;">Red</span>&nbsp;<span style="letter-spacing: 0px;">Blue</span>`

Comment: Try putting the `&nbsp;` inside the Red `span`?